# ILog or ILogger?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net

Should I be using the ILog or ILogger interface? I find the ILog interface to be easier to use since I can just declare one instance per class by calling:

```
private ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass));
```

It's a much simpler interface then the ILogger:

```
void Log(Type callerStackBoundaryDeclaringType, Level level, object message, Exception exception)
```

Is there a difference? When is it better to use 1 vs the other?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67419005/implement-log4net-in-a-windows-service-using-dependency-injection/67741410#67741410

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recommend the `ILog` interface.  This has been pushed by Apache/Common Logging.  If you use the common logging interface, then most logging systems can be plugged into your application.

I find log4net to be more than adequate.