# Implement log4net in a windows service using dependency injection

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, windows-services, autofac, log4net

I want to write error if occur in log file in a windows service which runs in every 10 minutes. I am using .net framework 4.6 and using Dependency Injection with autofac. I want to use Microsoft.Extensions.Logging dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this in a Windows Service, with ASP.Net 4.8, and Autofac for DI. I also didn't have to add any assembly info in `AssemblyInfo.cs`, because I put the config info in the `app.config`, instead of a separate config file.

**app.config** put this at the top of your `app.config` file just after `<configuration>`

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    </configSections>
```

**log4net configuration** put this at the bottom of your `app.config` file, just inside `</configuration>`. It will print to your visual studio output window and to a file called myservice.log

```
<log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="console" />
      <appender-ref ref="file" />
    </root>
    <appender name="console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="file" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="myservice.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

**Program.cs**

```
static void Main()
{
            ContainerBuilder cb = new ContainerBuilder();
            cb.RegisterType<MyService>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            ServiceBase.Run(container.Resolve<MyService>());
}
```

**MyService.cs**

```
private readonly ILog _logger;
public MyService(ILog logger)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _logger = logger;
    _logger.Info("Hello World!");
}
```

Comment: No problem, I had been searching for a solution for a few hours and never found the same answer in more than one place. It was frustrating.